# Pop-up Menu in iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, xcode, menu, popup

I'm designing a tab-based app, and I want a menu to pop up from one of the tabs when the user taps it. Like in the WaveSense Diabetes Manager app (I would post pictures, but I'm a new user and SO won't allow it. It's a free download if you would like to check it out; it has a cool design that you can take some ideas from).

Tapping a tab bar icon brings up a little pop-up menu, as opposed to switching the UIViewController. I've looked everywhere and have no idea how make something like this. I'm guessing modifications have to be made to the UITabBarController? Is the pop-up menu a custom UIView? Please help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The tab bar delegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITabBarDelegate) has a method `tabBar:didSelectItem:`. You could render your menu at that time, animating it up from the tabBar if you wanted.

As far as creating the menu, a UIView with a UITableView contained in it would work great. You can make the view smaller than the width of the device screen if you like, to get the effect of it being a menu which slides up. It would also allow you to have more menu entries than would comfortably fit on the screen.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am using a UITabBarController set up automatically by XCode (by selecting Tab-Based Application when creating a new project), so I ended up having to subclass UITabBarController to edit tabBar:didSelectItem: from there. 
Still, when touched, the tabs automatically change the displayed UIViewController. Is there a way to override this? I need the view to remain unchanged, but a pop-up menu to appear.
As for creating the actual menu, I think I will go with a UIView and custom buttons with images because I only need four options. But thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: If the TabBarItem doesn't have an associated UIViewController set, it won't have a view to switch to.